# String returned from function is wrong

Tags: c, memory-management

This is my code:

```
char *genWord(int wordLen){
    char array[wordLen + 1];
    char *word;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i <= wordLen; i++){
        array[i] = 'a';
    }

    array[wordLen] = '\0';

    //Test1 printf
    printf("%s \n", array);

    word = array;

    //Test 2
    printf("%s \n", word);

    return word;
}

main(){
    char *word;
    int wordLen = 10;

    word = (char *)genWord(wordLen);

    //Test 3
    printf("%s", word);       
}
```

And this is my output of 3 (same prog) executes in Linux gcc:

1st:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
aaaaaaaaaaaaT��aaaaa
```

2nd:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
aaaaaaaaaaaa�ƃ�aaaaa
```

3rd:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
aaaaaaaaaaaa����aaaaa
```

Can't figure out what's wrong and even worse, can't imagine how can i get a different output on every run? variable word can't have garbage in a part of the string right?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning local address, which is not anymore guaranteed to be allocated after the return from call. Therefore it is an undefined behaviour.

When you do `word = array` the local address of the array is copied into `word` variable. After return the calling function has the address, which was the local address in the function. But after the function return the address is not anymore valid, and may be allocated for other purpose, or overwritten or anything.

Do `word = strdup (array);` OR

```
word = malloc (sizeof (char) * (strlen (array) + 1));
strcpy (word, array);
return word;
```

Answer (score 4):

You return a reference to memory which had been allocated in the stack (`array`).

This memory is freed autmatically when returning from `genWord()`.

That's why the reference returned does not refer to any valid memory anymore.

To fix this issue

- either allocate the memory needed by `genWord()` dynamically (*inside* `genWord()`),
- or pass in a buffer to `genWord()` (from *outside* of `genWord()`), to which you copy the data needed.

---

As a side note: So called C-strings are zero-terminated. That is the character array representing the string takes a `NUL`character (decimal `0`) as its last (terminating) element (which's position would be indexed by the value of `i`,  not by `wordLen` in your code).

**The `str*`family of functions essentially relies on the terminating `0`, to determine the 'length' of the string.**

So if building up a string character by character, as `genWord()` does, make sure to add the terminating `0` after the last element when done. Alternativly (although more expensive, but also more convinient) just initialise the whole buffer with `0`s before using it.

Comment: I've read that using malloc inside my function 1st suggestion is not the best solution due, so i'd prefer your 2nd suggestion but so i can understand exactly what u are saying... you mean i should follow something like this?:

    word = (char *)genWord(wordLen, word);

where 

    char *genWord(int wordLen, char *word){
        //bla bla bla bla
    }

Did i get it right?

Comment: @GeorgeF-bot: Yes, you do. Btw: There is no need to cast `genWord()`'s return value.